# Why is the WaitForExit not an available method in my C# code?

Tags: c#, methods, process

The code below works fine but I need to add the WaitForExit method. But it doesn't show as being available. What am I missing? Thanks.

```
ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/C " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Setupws.exe");
process.Verb = "runas";
process.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(process);
```

Comment: Do you mean `WaitForExit`?

Comment: OMG I'm sorry, Yes I meant WaitForExit.

Comment: Your local variable `process` above is of type `ProcessStartInfo`. The `WaitForExit` method doesn't sit on that object. Instead it is on the `Process` object returned by your call to the static `Start` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WaitForExit()` is an instance method, which requires that you create an instance of `Process` and run that, rather than using the static `Process.Start()` without capturing the Process return value.

Once you create the `Process` instance and set the `ProcessStartInfo` on it, you call it's `Start()` instance method, then call `WaitForExit()` on the instance.

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
//Set info properties...
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = info;
//set other process properties...
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Additionally, as PheonixReborn notes in his excellent answer, the `Process.Start()` static method returns a `Process` instance, which you could use to call `process.WaitForExit()`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I better understand what's going on.

Comment: When you mention the `info` variable in your code example, I think you should show how it's with the `Process` object.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
    ProcessStartInfo process = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/C " +          AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Setupws.exe");
    process.Verb = "runas";
    process.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process p = Process.Start(process);
    p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I always forget that `Process.Start()` returns the `Process` instance! Good call! +1

Comment: Thank you PhoenixReborn. Welcome to the site.